# FFMPEG Real Time Audio

Tags: linux, audio, ffmpeg, real-time

I have looked everywhere for the answer but my head is spinning a little bit and I can't seem to find the final answer.

My goal is to get audio from my microphone in buffers of 512 audio samples, process it with LV2 plugins in audio buffers of 512 audio samples, and naturally output the audio back in buffers of 512 audio samples.

The best I've got so far is:

ffmpeg -f alsa -i hw:0 -rtbufsize 512 -blocksize 512 -flush_packets 1 -filter_complex "asetnsamples=512,lv2=p=some_plugin_here" -f alsa hw:0

I am hoping this results in my audio being entirely sampled and processed in buffers of 512, but I can't be entirely sure. I assume I should add the -ar option to define the 48000kHz samplerate, I would then expect a latency of 512/48000=10.66ms.

Is this correct ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: If ffmpeg has to buffer up 512 samples before it can start processing them, then 10.66ms is the *minimum* latency. The actual processing time that it takes your plugins to do their work will likely add additional latency.

Comment: I think you are right. I'm a beginner with real time audio so I'm not entirely sure what I am doing. I suppose I want ffmpeg to process the 512 samples in less than 10.66ms though, so that buffers can be delivered to the output without audio dropouts. So... 10.66ms to gather samples, than x seconds to process them and send out, and from there I must receive the next buffer (wait for it to be gathered) and be able to process it again in x seconds or less, else I get an underrun ?...

Comment: Sorry, I just said crazy ramblings. I think I can only read from and write to my audio card during an interrupt, and so the requirement is that I process my data in less time than a buffer size (in my case 10.66ms). I must then fill my output buffer at the next interrupt. So the expected latency should be 21.32ms I think.

Comment: I've made a basic measurement with the following command:
ffmpeg -f alsa -i hw:0 -rtbufsize 512 -blocksize 512 -flush_ packets 1 -filter_complex "asetnsamples=512,ashowinfo" -f alsa hw:0

but my basic measurement shows 38ms latency. It's quite good, but not the 21.32ms I was expecting. Why is that ?

Thank you very much.